# Ошибка 403 Forbidden с favicon.ico

Tags: html, веб-программирование, вёрстка

**Проблема с favicon.ico**
Всё сделал как было написано.
Вот код:
`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">`

Comment: А если использовать относительные ссылки href="img/icon.png" ?

Comment: С относительной ссылкой тоже не работает

Comment: вот как я юзаю: <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon.png" sizes="64x64" /> , может у вас нет этого файла favicon.ico  в images?

Comment: Есть favicon.ico ,но юзаю я по другому.

Comment: Если делать как ты делаешь то всё равно не работает

Comment: а если перейти по адресу http://127.0.0.1/images/favicon.ico иконка видна будет?

Comment: Нет ,пишет 403 Forbidden

Comment: Похоже проблема в доступе к файлу или директории

Comment: А можешь подсказать в чем именно?

Comment: права надо глянуть на папку images и на файл favicon.ico На линуксе веб сервер?

Comment: Да на линуксе. Где можно права глянуть ,а то я совсем новичок

Comment: в консоли ls -l /var/www/html/images , только путь на свой замени =)

Comment: Но ls -l только выводит файлы в виде списка

Comment: ну да, а в начале что-то вроде вот такого должно быть: drwxrwxr-x

Comment: Всё равно не работает